# Character encoding not being picked up

Tags: html, character-encoding

http://www.mamstore.co.uk/bin/pxisapi1.exe/catalogue?level=805838

Look where its (meant to say) £5 T-shirts. Instead the '£' comes up as an invalid character, yet the exact same char is shown just below on the products.

I am getting the same when i pull a php files contents in with Jquery.  The actual PHP file shows the chars correctly (without any head/body set etc) as soon as i pull it into the site it suddenly has issues with it.

Its stored in an SQL DB on a custom build CMS / WMS system.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page is encoded with UTF, but character in breadcrumbs is encoded with ISO. What encoding do you have in your database?

Comment: Unfortunately i do not have access to the DB, the products + breadcrumb are filled in with commands such as <#breadcrumb> and pre processed using the CMS/WMS. 

Will this fix if i contacted the DB administrator and got him to change encoding to UTF.. or if i were to change the whole site to ISO?

Comment: It looks like your site does not need any characters beyond ISO-8895-1, so you could switch to it, or perhaps better windows-1252. It means going in a wrong direction, but the practical situation seems to suggest it. But what encoding will your online shop use?

Comment: tbh its an ongoing contract, and if it means im going to hit problems in the future not using UTF-8 i would rather change over, i will contact the guy incharge of the DB and see if he can change the DB to UTF-8. Thanks for the help!